# char arrays length in C

Tags: c

In C, you have to declare the length of an array:

```
int myArray[100];
```

But when you're dealing with `char`s and strings, the length can be left blank:

```
char myString[] = "Hello, World!";
```

Does the compiler generate the length for you by looking at the string?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly declare the length of an `int` array either: `int a[] = {1,2,3};`

Comment: All answers are correct, all upvoted. I always feel silly when I can't decide which answer is the best.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not unique to `char`.  You could do this, for instance:

```
int myNumbers[] = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 42 };
```

This is equivalent to writing:

```
int myNumbers[5] = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 42 };
```

Initialising a `char` array from a string literal is a special case.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's the length including the terminating `'\0'`.

Answer (score 5):

> Does the compiler generate the length for you by looking at the string?

Yes, that's exactly why it works.  The compiler sees the constant value, and can fill in the length so you don't have to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the compiler knows the length of the string and allocates the appropriate space.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same deal if you did something like...

```
int x[] = {1,2,3};
```

Answer (score 2):

The size of the string literal (not length as in `strlen`) is used to size the array being initialized.

You can initialize a char array with a string literal which has embedded null bytes. The resulting array will have size for all the bytes after the first (or second, ...) null.

```
char array[] = "foo\0bar\0baz\0quux";
/* sizeof array is 17
** array[3] is 0
** printf("%s\n", array + 4); prints bar
** array[11] is 0
** printf("%s\n", array + 12); prints quux
** array[16] == 0
*/
```