# C++ getting length of char array using a second function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the length of a character array in a second function. I've looked at a few questions on here ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497077/char-arrays-length-in-c) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931453/length-of-a-char-array-in-c)) but they don't answer my particular question (although I'm sure something does, I just can't find it). My code is below, but I get the error "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'". I don't know how to convert my array to what is needed.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int ValidInput(char, char);

int main() {
    char user_input; // user input character
    char character_array[26];
    int valid_guess;
    valid_guess = ValidGuess(user_input, character_array);
    // another function to do stuff with valid_guess output
    return 0;    
}

int ValidGuess (char user_guess, char previous_guesses) {
    for (int index = 0; index < strlen(previous_guesses); index++) {
        if (user_guess == previous_guesses[index]) {
            return 0; // invalid guess
        }
    }
    return 1; // valid guess, reaches this if for loop is complete
}
```

Based on what I've done so far, I feel like I'm going to have a problem with previous_guesses[index] as well.

Comment: The answer is in the error message. Use `const char *previous_guess` in the parameter list of `ValidGuess`

Comment: You have mismatched types for your function declaration. You're passing an array of characters to `ValidGuess`, which is defined with just a regular `char`.https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm    The second and third ways are probably what you want to use for the moment if you're not familiar with pointers.

Comment: I think this may just be a typo: `int ValidGuess (char user_guess, char* previous_guesses) {` would be fine. Although, happening twice, makes it less likely to be unintentional... OP can you please clarify?

Comment: @Dortimer This may be confusing, because `void myFunction(int param[]) {}` doesn't actually take an array by value as argument. It is interpreted exactly the same as `void myFunction(int *param) {`, i.e. it is still passing a pointer, not an array.

Comment: Handy reading: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: @uneven_mark yes, it was unintentional. I’m still very much learning this (still in college), so I’m not always sure what is happening when something like this goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char user_input;
```

defines a single character

```
char character_array[26];
```

defines an array of 26 characters.

```
valid_guess = ValidGuess(user_input, character_array);
```

calls the function

```
int ValidGuess (char user_guess, char previous_guesses)
```

where `char user_guess` accepts a single character, lining up correctly with the `user_input` argument, and `char previous_guesses` accepts a single character, not the 26 characters of `character_array`. `previous_guesses` needs a different type to accommodate `character_array`. This be the cause of the reported error.

Where this gets tricky is `character_array` will [decay to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying), so

```
int ValidGuess (char user_guess, char previous_guesses)
```

could be changed to

```
int ValidGuess (char user_guess, char * previous_guesses)
```

or

```
int ValidGuess (char user_guess, char previous_guesses[])
```

both ultimately mean the same thing.

Now for where things get REALLY tricky. When an array decays to a pointer it loses how big it is. The asker has gotten around this problem, kudos, with `strlen` which computes the length, but this needs a bit of extra help. `strlen` zips through an array, counting until it finds a null terminator, and there are no signs of `character_array` being null terminated. This is bad. Without knowing where to stop `strlen` will probably keep going<sup>1</sup>. A quick solution to this is go back up to the definition of `character_array` and change it to

```
char character_array[26] = {};
```

to force all of the slots in the array to 0, which just happens to be the null character.

That gets the program back on its feet, but it could be better. Every call to `strlen` may recount (compilers are smart and could compute once per loop and store the value if it can prove the contents won't change) the characters in the string, but this is still at least one scan through every entry in `character_array` to see if it's null when what you really want to do is scan for `user_input`. Basically the program looks at every item in the array twice.

Instead, look for both the null terminator and `user_input` in the same loop.

```
int index = 0;
while (previous_guesses[index] != '\0' ) {
    if (user_guess == previous_guesses[index]) {
        return 0; // prefer returning false here. The intent is clearer
    }
    index++;
}
```

You can also wow your friends by using pointers and eliminating the need for the `index` variable.

```
while (*previous_guesses != '\0' ) {
    if (user_guess == *previous_guesses) {
        return false; 
    }
    previous_guesses++;
}
```

The compiler knows and uses this trick too, so use the one that's easier for you to understand.

For 26 entries it probably doesn't matter, but if you really want to get fancy, or have a lot more than 26 possibilities, use a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or a [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). They allow only one of an item and have much faster look-up than scanning a list one by one, so long as the list is large enough to get over the added complexity of a set and take advantage of its smarter logic. `ValidGuess` is replaced with something like

```
if (used.find(user_input) != used.end())
```

Side note: Don't forget to make the user read a value into `user_input` before the program uses it. I've also left out how to store the previous inputs because the question does as well.

<sup>1</sup> I say probably because the Standard doesn't say what to do. This is called [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). C++ is littered with the stuff. Undefined Behaviour can do anything -- work, not work, visibly not work, look like it works until it doesn't, melt your computer, anything -- but what it usually does is the easiest and fastest thing. In this case that's just keep going until the program crashes or finds a null.

Comment: This was perfect, much better explanation than anything I’ve found online, thank you so much